# Is it allowed to read namaz with a non mehram?

Tags: salat

Assalam alaikum. I'm a 17_ year old girl from India . I go to tuitions in the evening here timings is from 5-8. And hence I had to read the Magrib Namaz(prayer) from the tuitions. And along with me there is one more guy who reads his namaz. We pray in the same hall but at the different corners. My question is that is it allowed to read namaz along with a non mehram? And is there anything that me or him are going against Islam which we are not aware of? Please do reply. Allah hafiz

Answer (score 2):

You can not perform prayer alone with a non-mehram because you can not be alone with a non-mahram in any condition https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:990

> No man must not be alone with a woman except in the presence of her
> (Mahram).

Answer (score -1):

no in general if there no neccessity you can do it but in islam it is said tha a woman should pray ta home and it is more better to pray in a room ana best is to pray in a corner of a room w r not even allowed to see a non mehram for second time than how can we say prayer with him even if we do it in different corners i do not think so u can pray after reaching home allah knows that u r not doing it willingly